# How to identify which way the product qty was updated in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.4, magento2.4.5, qty

I have 3 ways to update the product quantity.

1. using product edit page in magento admin
2. using magento API
3. Using magento csv import

I wanted to know while updating the qty of a product which method (above mentioned 3 methods) it is. Means is there any flag by default magento providing to identify which way we are updating qty of a Product ?